# Is it possible to share sessions across multiple domains in Rails 4 applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I know how to share sessions across subdomains in Rails applications.
e.g. sharing sessions between "main.example.com" and "sub.example.com"

However, this time what I want to do is sharing sessions across multiple domains.
e.g. "example1.com" and "example2.com"

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any information about this so far.

Is this possible? 
If it is possible, how can I do? If not, I will give it up and have no choice but to throw one of the domains away.

Any help is greatly appreciated.